# How is this webpage blocking me when I scrape through a loop but not when I access it directly?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a set of webpages.  When I scrape from one webpage directly, I am able to access the html.  However, when I iterate through a pd dataframe to scrape a set of webpages, even a dataframe with only one row, I see a truncated html and cannot extract my desired data.

Iterating through a dataframe of 1 row:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

first_names = pd.Series(['Robert'], index = [0])
last_names = pd.Series(['McCoy'], index = [0])
names = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['first_name', 'last_name'])
names['first_name'] = first_names
names['last_name'] = last_names

freq = []

for first_name, last_name in names.iterrows():
    url = "https://zbmath.org/authors/?q={}+{}".format(first_name, 
    last_name)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    html=str(html)
    frequency = re.findall('Joint\sPublications">(.*?)</a>', html)
    freq.append(frequency)

print(freq)
```

[[]]

Accessing the webpage directly.  Same code, but now not blocked.

```
url = "https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=robert+mccoy"
r = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
html=str(html)
frequency = re.findall('Joint\sPublications">(.*?)</a>', html)
freq.append(frequency)

print(freq)
```

[[], ['10', '8', '6', '5', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]

How can I loop through multiple webpages but not get blocked?

Comment: First of all, you are likely violating the site's terms of service by hitting them with a bunch of automated requests very quickly. Second, they are likely rate-limiting you based on their DDOS filters. The way around this is to slow your requests to a reasonable amount of traffic, generally using `time.sleep` between `requests.get()` calls

Comment: But why would the site block me when I'm iterating through a loop of length one?  In my code above I only hit the site with a single query and I'm still blocked.  (Also I have been using time.sleep and I'm still blocked.)

Comment: Check the output of `itterrows`. It doesn't give you column values, it gives you tuples of `(index, (columns))` that you need to parse deeper

Comment: Hm.  I don't think itterrows is the problem, because when I run iterrows and print the html, I still see a proper set of html, albeit one that has all of my desired data truncated.

Comment: The only difference between the working and non-working calls is `url = "https://zbmath.org/authors/?q={}+{}".format(first_name, 
    last_name)` vs `url = "https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=robert+mccoy"`, so have you printed the url string to verify that it is indeed the same?

Comment: Just for fun, try `for _, (first_name, last_name) in names.iterrows():`

Comment: OHHH!!!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH, G. Anderson.  You were totally right.  What a silly oversight!!!  I really appreciate this.  Thanks for responding to both of my queries -- I'm new to SO and am very impressed by the generosity of the community!

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added that as an answer so you can accept it and close out the question. I would still recommend adding a sleep in your loop to prevent problems down the line from rate-limiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterrows returns a tuple of (index,(columns)), so the solution is to parse it slightly differently:

```
for _,(first_name, last_name) in names.iterrows():
    url = "https://zbmath.org/authors/?q={}+{}".format(first_name, 
    last_name)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    html=str(html)
    frequency = re.findall('Joint\sPublications">(.*?)</a>', html)
    freq.append(frequency)

print(freq)
```